# How change the default DB prefix and table names in Consolibyte Quickbooks Web Connector

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm using the [Consolibyte Quickbooks Web Connector](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) PHP Library and testing the example app in `web_connector/example_app_web_connector/`and it works in most parts. However, it generates its own DB prefix & tables names upon initialization. I'm wondering how I can override them so that I can use my own database naming structure.

I've seen that they were defined in `QuickBooks/Driver/Sql.php` but I know it's not a good idea to directly change the values from there.

I found `$driver_options = []` but I'm not sure what option keys to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `define` the prefix before including the code.

`define('QUICKBOOKS_DRIVER_SQL_MYSQLI_PREFIX', 'your_custom_prefix');`

Reference this:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/Driver/Sql/Mysqli.php#L47

Where the code does this to allow you to override the prefix:

```
if (!defined('QUICKBOOKS_DRIVER_SQL_MYSQLI_PREFIX'))
{
    define('QUICKBOOKS_DRIVER_SQL_MYSQLI_PREFIX', QUICKBOOKS_DRIVER_SQL_PREFIX);
}
```

Comment: Oh I completely missed that! Thanks Keith.